# How to override Material-UI Chip deleteIcon / cancelIcon?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I've created a custom theme and I've successfully created a bunch of overrides for various components.

I'm using an **Autocomplete** component with "*multiple*" enabled so each option I add gets added inside as a **Chip** that has an icon to remove it which I'm trying to change.
I wish to do this override on a higher level as I think that's the only solution for me as I'm not actually importing the **Chip** component but it's created by the **Autocomplete** component I'm using.

[image: Screenshot of Chips inside the Autocomplete component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Autocomplete component has ChipProps property: "Props applied to the Chip element"

```
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';

<Autocomplete
  multiple
  ChipProps={{ deleteIcon: <DoneIcon /> }}
  ...
/>
```